# Interference of em waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, radiation, interference

If EM waves interfere, how is it that wave that is in my line of sight does not interfere with wave that is in someone else's line of sight which intersects my line of sight, and consequently make disturbances in what I see?

Answer (score 2):

The word *interference* is a misnomer as it implies that one wave does something to the other so that the emerging waves from a *region of interference* (a region where the waves overlap) are different from the waves which emerge from that region.
That is not the case as the waves do superpose (overlap) but do not change each others properties.
What is observed in the region of interference is the result of the two waves disturbing the medium simultaneously.

This means that the light waves entering your eye are not affect by light waves which have crossed the path of the waves which entered your eye.

Comment: What you are saying is what I can witness in everyday life, but seems at odds with what any attempt to construct science based mental model of behavior of light (and other EM waves) leads me to.